# App for ranking Angular Repositories contributors on GitHub with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angular, github

I'm trying to learn Angular.js, I got past the tutorials and now it is time for coding.

My friend applied for a job few months ago that required few angular.js challenge to complete, one of them got my attention to solve but I got stuck at the beginning of it. So here I'm looking for help.

The goal of this challenge is to create an app that will rank Angular repositories contributors and show them in one list.To narrow the scope
I need to focus for the purpose of this exercise on Angular repo [Link to Angular Repo](https://github.com/angular)

The requirements:

1. The rank should be filterable by amount of contributions made by developer to all Angular repositories, by amount of followers, public repos & gists he/she published.
2. The rank should be filterable by amount of contributions made by developer to all Angular repositories, by amount of followers, public repos & gists he/she published.
3. We should be able to navigate to repository details page where we can find other contributors.

There is no problem for me to create some code to display data according to this requirements with Angular.js, the problem is how to get this data out of GitHub API?

I tried to find a way to get the data out of GitHub API v3 but it does not show data that I need for this exercise. I can either get the data about the first 30 out of 170 of repos for the Angular page provided [Link to Api Page](https://api.github.com/users/angular/repos), or I can get info about specific user and his total contributions.

How can I get all of that info out of GitHub API to follow all of above requirements, I tried to get to the next pages for Angular repos but it shows error: Not Found. Also how can I get all of the information about users that are contributing to this specific account of Angular.js

Sorry for no code but there is really nothing to show now, there is no point for pasting code here because it is working, the problem is finding required data.

Thank you for all help and suggestions,

Comment: There are docs for the GitHub API here: https://developer.github.com/v3/ That sounds like the best place to start.

Comment: Yes I managed to get to this docs, the thing is that I cant find a way to pull out all of the required data by using API, it either shows info about repos or info about specific user, and I need info about users based on repos from Angular Topic.

Comment: Also I was thinking about creating a loop on array that will include all links to the repos, then from those gather info about users like name, followers and repos for example and to place that data in new array. Then from that array get it to display in table. But is it possible to load specified data from $HTTP.GET and save it to array and then create loop for it that will use $http.get again to find next data? I did not see anything like that in any of the Angular tutorials and it just seem like over kill for this kind of simple app.